# constructor vs babel returns an error anything I do without using babel.

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and on the course they are using the create-react-app, I'm trying to code along but somehow I don't think that babel is working for me so I need to use the constructor and super even though the course I'm following isn't. I have managed to follow along until I got to this lesson that used static.

the code the lesson gives is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'   

class Xpto extends Component {
  static propTypes = { //some props }
}
render() {
  // some logic
}
```

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Xpto extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    static propTypes = { //some props }
  }
  render() {
    // some logic
  }
}
```

The issue is that when I use this, it returns this error:

```
Syntax error: static is a reserved word in strict mode (10:4)
```

if I move it outside of the constructor but inside the class it says that `propTypes` isn't defined and if i remove static and use `this.propTypes` it works but returns an error in the console saying to use static.

I don't get what is happening or how to resolve this situation. Asked a friend that has done some work with React and he told me he didn't know either to get babel working and use the course approach but I'm stubborn and like to know what is going on so I'm reaching out to you.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: it should be outside of the constructor but inside of the class. could you share the exact error when it's outside of the constructor?

Comment: The error is that the `propTypes is undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining the `propTypes` outside of the class:

```js
class Xpto extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { name = 'Dan Abramov' } = this.props;
    return <div>{name}</div>;
  }
}

// You can define propTypes and defaultProps here
Xpto.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

If that does work, try removing the `constructor`.

If it doesn't work, though, post the error and we'll go from there.

Comment: Yes that works just fine, it is how I was doing it but the lesson moved it into the class so I thought there might be some difference but I guess not. I was just researching and it seems that babel transpiles it out somehow. The syntax the lesson is showing doesn't seem to be supported yet. Thanks for your help though. I will keep using it outside until it is supported or my i figure how to configure babel to work with the new syntax.

Comment: no problem. Thanks for the help anyways, appreciate it.